How to list commits of a remote tag
As long as git fetch origin is executed, git log origin/<branch_name> can list commits of the given branch. However, when I tried to git log origin/tag_name there is the following error
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/tag_name': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Question: How to list commits of a remote tag?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+ambiguous+argument+tag+unknown+revision+or+path+not+in+the+working+tree

Tags are not local or remote, tags belong to their own namespace. git fetch origin --tags && git log tag-name

Remote tags are not a thing. refs/remotes/<name>/ is reserved for remote-tracking branches. Imagine if tags could also be in that namespace. Then git-fetch(1) wouldn’t know what to do if the remote both had a tag and a branch named something.
